# Evaluate scalar function on numpy array with conditionals

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

I have a numpy array `r` and I need to evaluate a scalar function, let's say `np.sqrt(1-x**2)` on each element `x` of this array. However, I want to return the value of the function as zero, whenever `x>1`, and the value of the function on `x` otherwise.
The final result should be a numpy array of scalars.

How could I write this the most pythonic way?

Comment: use `np.where`. See [examples](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like `numpy.where(condition,if condition holds,otherwise)` so `np.where(x>1,0,np.sqrt(1-x**2))` will be answer

Comment: This still produces a runtime warning

Answer (score 2):

With the plain evaluation:

```
In [19]: f=lambda x:np.sqrt(1-x**2)

In [20]: f(np.linspace(0,2,10))
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1604\1368662409.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  f=lambda x:np.sqrt(1-x**2)
Out[20]: 
array([1.        , 0.97499604, 0.89580642, 0.74535599, 0.45812285,
              nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan])
```

This produces `nan` and a warning for `x>1`.  `np.where` as suggested by other answers can change the `nan` to `0`, but you'll still get the warning.  The warning can be silenced.  But an alternative is to use the `where` parameter of `np.sqrt` (and other `ufunc`):

```
In [21]: f=lambda x:np.sqrt(1-x**2, where=x<=1, out=np.zeros_like(x))

In [22]: f(np.linspace(0,2,10))
Out[22]: 
array([1.        , 0.97499604, 0.89580642, 0.74535599, 0.45812285,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ])
```

Comment: I think you need parenthesis on `where=(x<=1)`, since it does not work on my machine (python version 3.8.16, numpy version 1.21.6)

Answer (score 0):

```
y = np.where(
   r>1, #if r[i]>1:
   0, #y[i]=0
   np.sqrt(1-r**2) #else: y[i] = (1-r[i]**2)
)
```

Comment: This produces a runtime warning for x>1

Comment: @hpaulj it does